# combineLatest. continue observables after getting error

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, combinelatest

I have couple of observables combined in one observable with  [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest). Also I have one inner `switchMap` observable that in real example makes an http request to remote server.

Now I wonder, how can the combined observable continue working in case if `switchMap` returns error ?

I've created  simplified example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-combinelatest-error?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts)

```
//emit every 2.5 seconds
const first = interval(2500);
//emit every 2 seconds
const second = interval(2000);
//emit every 1.5 seconds
const third = interval(1500);
//emit every 1 second
const fourth = interval(1000);

let count = 0;

//emit outputs from one observable
const example = combineLatest(
  first.pipe(mapTo("FIRST!")),
  second.pipe(mapTo("SECOND!")),
  third.pipe(mapTo("THIRD")),
  fourth.pipe(mapTo("FOURTH"))
)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      console.log(data);
      count++;
      // here lets asume in some cases http request getting error
      return count < 5 ? of("switchMap") : throwError("This is an error!");
    }),
    catchError(err => of(err))
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Output

```
["FIRST!", "SECOND!", "THIRD", "FOURTH"]
switchMap
["FIRST!", "SECOND!", "THIRD", "FOURTH"]
switchMap
["FIRST!", "SECOND!", "THIRD", "FOURTH"]
switchMap
["FIRST!", "SECOND!", "THIRD", "FOURTH"]
switchMap
["FIRST!", "SECOND!", "THIRD", "FOURTH"]
This is an error!
```

So after getting error `combineLatest` observable's work stops. In my real example I have 4 filters, and after changing filters I make http request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stream itself from the `combineLatest` will end when an error occurs.
You can prevent it by adding the `catchError` to the Observable returned in your `switchMap`.

That way, the main stream is not altered and will continue to live.

```
const first  = interval(2500);
const second = interval(2000);
const third  = interval(1500);
const fourth = interval(1000);

let count = 0;

combineLatest(
  first.pipe(mapTo("FIRST!")),
  second.pipe(mapTo("SECOND!")),
  third.pipe(mapTo("THIRD")),
  fourth.pipe(mapTo("FOURTH"))
).pipe(
  switchMap(data => {
    count++;
    const obs$ = count < 5
      ? of("switchMap")
      : throwError("This is an error!");

    return obs$.pipe(
      catchError(err => of(err))
    );
  })
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```